# How to do endswith string replacement in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, replace

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
      Company Name     ID
0        Finl Corp    111
1          Fund Tr    222
2          Invt Fd    333           
3          Govt Fd    444
4      Trinity Inc    555
```

And I'm replacing strings that are commonly abbreviated:

```
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace('Finl', 'Financial')
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace('Tr', 'Trust')
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace('Invt', 'Investment')
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace('Fd', 'Fund')
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace('Govt', 'Government')
```

But how do I replace `Tr` with `Trust` *only* when `Tr` is the last two characters of a string, like row `1` (but not row `4`)?

Can I do something like?

`df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.endswith(' Tr').replace(' Tr', ' Trust')` so that the output is:

```
      Company Name    ID  
0   Financial Corp   111
1       Fund Trust   222
2  Investment Fund   333
3  Government Fund   444
4      Trinity Inc   555
```

Comment: What's the expected output here; should `Govt` get changed too, even though it's not the end of the string 'Govt Fd'?

Comment: Yes, good question. I've updated it so that it's clearer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `$` to match the end of the line in `replace`:

```
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace(' Tr$', ' Trust')
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace more than one thing at once using `replace` with `regex=True`:

```
repl_dict = {'Govt': 'Government', 'Fd$': 'Fund',}                                                                                                  
df['Company Name'].replace({k : v for k, v in repl_dict.items()}, 
                           regex=True)                                                            

0          Finl Corp
1            Fund Tr
2          Invt Fund
3    Government Fund
4        Trinity Inc
Name: Company Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: How about handling all of the cases with a dictionary like: `{'Govt$': 'Government', 'Fd$': 'Fund', 'Finl': 'Financial', 'Invt': 'Investment'}`.

Comment: I should have made this clearer in the original question, but how would I make it so that the other strings (e.g., `Finl` > `Financial`, `Govt` > `Government`, etc) get replaced correctly too?

Comment: @MSD if you use `repl_dict = {'Govt': 'Government', 'Tr$':'Trust', 'Fd': 'Fund', 'Finl': 'Financial', 'Invt': 'Investment'} ` and then  `{k : v for k, v in repl_dict.items()}` in the replace, you will do everything at once I think

Comment: @MSD Hmm didn't realise that was the requirement. Please take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `def expand_trust(s):` helper function,
that replaces "Tr" with "Trust".

Then use [`.apply( ... )`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to modify your dataframe:

```
df["Company Name"] = df["Company Name"].apply(expand_trust)
```

Your helper *can* use `.endswith( ... )`,
but you might find that `$` in a regex is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `str.replace` if you first select the rows you want to replace with `df.loc` and assign them to the corresponding replacement string:

```
df.loc[df['Company Name'].str.endswith('Finl')] = 'Financial'
```

I suggest putting the text/replacement duos in a dictionary and perform this in a loop, instead of repeatedly overwriting the whole `df['Company Name']` column, e.g:

```
replace_dict = {'Finl': 'Financial', 
                'Tr': 'Trust', 
                'Invt': 'Investment', 
                'Fd': 'Fund', 
                'Govt': 'Government'}

for k, v in replace_dict.items(): 
    df.loc[df['Company Name'].str.endswith(k)] = v
```